# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined" when calling firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to create the Auth state observer I am met with the error message shown below. I have stripped down my function to be as minimal as possible (see code snipped) but the error still persists.

```
1: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
2:     if (user) {
3:       // User is signed in.
4:       console.log(user)
5:     } else {
6:       // No user is signed in.
7:       console.log("no user")
8:     }
9:   });
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at X.h.onAuthStateChanged (firebase-auth.js:194)
    at X.a [as onAuthStateChanged] (firebase-auth.js:142)
    at existingUserLogin (index.min.js:2)
    at (index):150
```

`(index):150` is the location of the function `existingUserLogin()`

`(index.min.js:2)`refers to `line 1` of the included code snippet

The `onAuthStateChanged()` method contains the following:

```
fireauth.Auth.prototype.onAuthStateChanged = function(
    nextOrObserver, opt_error, opt_completed) {
  var self = this;
  // State already determined. Trigger immediately, otherwise initState will
  // take care of notifying all pending listeners on initialization.
  // In this case we do not trigger synchronously and trigger via a resolved
  // promise as required by specs.
  if (this.isStateResolved_) {
    // The observer cannot be called synchronously. We're using the
    // native Promise implementation as otherwise it creates weird behavior
    // where the order of promises resolution would not be as expected.
    // It is due to the fact fireauth and firebase.app use their own
    // and different promises library and this leads to calls resolutions order
    // being different from the promises registration order.
    Promise.resolve().then(function() {
      // This ensures that the first time notifyAuthListeners_ is triggered,
      // it has the correct UID before triggering the user state change
      // listeners.
      self.userStateChangeUid_ = self.getUid();
      if (goog.isFunction(nextOrObserver)) {
        nextOrObserver(self.currentUser_());
      } else if (goog.isFunction(nextOrObserver['next'])) {
        nextOrObserver['next'](self.currentUser_());
      }
    });
  }
  return this.onUserStateChanged_(
      /** @type {!firebase.Observer|function(*)|undefined} */ (nextOrObserver),
      /** @type {function(!Error)|undefined} */ (opt_error),
      opt_completed);
};
```

Comment: I think the error might be being caused by `firebase.Promise.resolve()` bit of code. It looks like firebase does not have a Promise property, Promise is undefined therefore resolve can not be read.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought this was your code `h.onAuthStateChanged = function(a, b, c) {
        var d = this;
        this.kb && firebase.Promise.resolve().then(function() {
            n(a) ? a(Z(d)) : n(a.next) && a.next(Z(d))
        });
        return this.me(a, b, c)
    }` . Have you initialised the firebaseApp?

Comment: @Carlene Yes it's the first thing that happens in the body of my app, I'm using firebase firestore just fine in the same app.

Comment: I have found the uncompressed function [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/e3d740854b73336fac4871da5cf403a64b0ed890/packages/auth/src/auth.js#L1437) I'll update my post too

Comment: What version of firebase are you using @Frantiklee?

Comment: I just checked which versions I was importing from the CDN and firebase and firebase-firestore were from version 6.5.0 but firebase-auth was from 3.1.0 for some reason... In future I should probably take better care of my copy pasting... Thanks for helping me realise!

Comment: all sorted then @Frantiklee?

Comment: Yes thanks, after switching to the 6.5.0 version of auth everything was a lot more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, the solution was to make sure the correct/matching versions of firebase, firebase-firestore and firebase-auth are being used. It looks as though the error was being caused because the older version of firebase-auth makes use of the Promise property on firebase and the newer version of firebase no longer has a Promise property.